# CSS Font problem with printing

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I have changed my color in my CSS to white but when I print the file it shows up as black font. Can anyone tell me why this is?  Thanks :)

Comment: Your printer ran out of white ink. (Or perhaps there's a print stylesheet overriding your `color: white`)

Comment: Are you using a color or black and white printer?Do you have white ink?

Comment: When I print it in the .xps view it shows up as black. I'll look into the stylesheet problem and see if I can find it.

Comment: I was under the impression that most printers don't contain white ink considering paper is generally white.

Comment: Just in case anybody seriously didn't get it, "white ink for desktop printers" is almost akin to "a tin of striped paint" (a joke item).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a jquery called PrintArea and my image pops up into a lightbox when I view it. The text inside of that image shows white but when i print to .xps since i`m not using a printer it shows up as black. I also tried printing it off once but it showed black as well.

Comment: I`ll just use a very light color and use that as my "white" since it doesn't print with white ink. At least I understand why I can't print a white font haha.